# How to rename the x-labels in FacetGrid (Seaborn)?

Tags: python, plot, seaborn, axis-labels

SO I have this plot that i made with Seaborn:[image]

And What I want to do is , to rename the ***Week_Number***'s , putting ***Week_one*** rather thank ***Week_Number = 1*** , than ***Week_two*** rather than ***Week_Number = 44*** until ***Week_ten*** rather than ***Week_Number = 52***

And Here's My code:

```
 g = sns.FacetGrid(Res, col='Week_Number', col_wrap=4)
 g.map(plt.scatter, "Temperature","Wind_Speed")
 plt.show()
```

Thank's Everyone.